# Busemann-Feller lemma in hyperbolic space

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, convexity

The classical Busemann-Feller lemma in Euclidean space says the following.

Let $K\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a closed convex set.
Then

1. for any point $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ there exists unique nearest point in $K$; let us denote it by $p(x)$.
2. the map $p\colon  \mathbb{R}^n \to K$ does not increase distances, i.e. is 1-Lipschitz.

**Question. Does this result hold in an $n$-dimensional hyperbolic space? A reference would be helpful.**

Remark.  I think part (1) is true for hyperbolic and spherical spaces; in the spherical space one should require in addition that $K$ is contained in an open half-sphere.  I think part (2) is not true in the spherical space.

Comment: It is true in every CAT(0) space. Must be in Bridson-Haefliger.

Comment: Are you sure about (1) holding in spherical space? If $\pm p \in \mathbf{S}^n$ are antipodal and $D_r(p)$ is a closed disc around $p$, then the nearest points to $-p$ form $\partial D_r(p)$, no?

Comment: @LeoMoos: to be more precise one should consider everything in open half-sphere rather than sphere.

Comment: Note that in $\mathbb{R}^n$, if (1) is true for a compact set $K$ then $K$ must be convex. This is interstingly not true in $\mathbb{H}^n$, where horospheres are not flat. You can see that as several variants of convexity that no longer match (using either geodesic or busemann functions).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In any Hadamard space, projection into convex sets is non-expansive; see Proposition 2.4(4) in *[Metric spaces of non-positive curvature](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540643241)* by Bridson and Haefliger.

Comment: Also found in Ballmann's *lectures on Spaces of non-positive curvature,* Corollary 5.6.